# Removing Common elements in two List in O(n) Time Complexity

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose My Two Lists:

```
a=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
b=[1,2,3,4]
```

so, my resulting list should be

```
a1=[1,2,3]
b1=[4]
```

Please Help

Comment: testing for membership in a set is done in constant time https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how you can use list comprehensions:**

```
a=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
b=[1,2,3,4]

a1 = [v for i,v in enumerate(a) if v not in a[:i]]
b1 = [v for v in b if v not in a]
```

You *can* use sets like in Jan's answer, but then, you won't be able to retrieve elements from the arrays according to indexing. **This code keeps the order.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `sets(...)` and `-` on them:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a, b = map(set, [a, b])
b = b - a
print(a, b)
```

This yields

```
{1, 2, 3} {4}
```

Answer (score 0):

may u can use simple if checks to that like given below

```
a=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
b=[1,2,3,4]
x=[]
y=[]
for i in a:
    if i not in x:
        x.append (i)
for i in b:
    if i not in x and i not in y:
        y.append(i)
print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Build dict counting element occurrence
2. Find difference in occurrences
3. Populate final lists with difference in occurrences
   a.  version that does not preserve order just repeats element diff times
   b.  version that preserves order decrements counter for each occurrence, and filters out the element if counter is 0 or less
   (eg: element '4' occurs 2 times in a, but 3 times in b, diff is -1, don't keep any '4's.  But, if 6 times and 3 times, diff is 3, keep 3x '4's).

Version that does not preserve order:

```
import collections

a=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
b=[1,2,3,4]

# element counter O(n)
ac = collections.Counter(a)
bc = collections.Counter(b)

# union of all keys in dict O(n)
keys = set(ac) | set(bc)
# get difference for all counters O(n)
diff = {k: ac.get(k,0)-bc.get(k,0) for k in keys}

a1 = []
b1 = []
# iterate over all keys O(n)
for k,v in diff.items():
    a1+=[k]*v
    b1+=[k]*-v
    # concatenate to lists, repeat element v times

print(a1,b1)
```

Order preserving version:

```
import collections

a=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
b=[1,2,3,4]

# element counter O(n)
ac = collections.Counter(a)
bc = collections.Counter(b)

# get difference for all counters O(n)
diffa = {k: v-bc.get(k,0) for k,v in ac.items()}
diffb = {k: v-ac.get(k,0) for k,v in bc.items()}

a1 = []
b1 = []
# iterate over all keys O(n)
for x in a:
    if(diffa[x]>0):
      a1 += [x]
    diffa[x] -= 1

for x in b:
    if(diffb[x]>0):
        b1 += [x]
    diffb[x] -= 1

print(a1,b1)
```

Note: This has a high overhead cost for keeping complexity linear O(n) by building lookup tables (not to mention taking into account space complexity).  It is roughly around O(6n), so there is only a performance benefit when the lists are very, very large.  For small lists like the example in OP, just using an "in" lookup for each element will be faster, due to not having to create lookup tables.
If this isn't for a coding challenge, it's likely that you should be using a different approach to your data, or the complexity advantage here doesn't apply to you.  If it's for some kind of big data processing type task, your bottleneck will probably be in making proper use of generators and buffering/segmenting IO, and your framework already has better methods to deal with these things.

Comment: Can we do it in O(1) time complexity?

Comment: Are you asking that because you were asked to find a constant time algorithm as an assignment, or because you don't understand time complexity and are just hoping for a "faster" algorithm?  O(1) would mean that the amount of items to look at are bounded to  constants, and so it is by definition impossible because all elements of the array must be looked at at least once, unless there is some feature to the arrays that allows you to look at a constant number of indexes, which would require them to be both sorted and have a bound number of repetitions to make index positions bounded.

Comment: If your lists always have a set number of repetitions directly proportional to the size of the list, or some other similar pattern, your given pattern needs to be defined.  That pattern could allow the algorithm to have constant time.  The lists you have given in your question appear to have some pattern, but you have not defined the pattern, so it is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set()` but it may not keep order.

```
a = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
b = [1,2,3,4]

a1 = list( set(a) & set(b) )
b1 = list( set(a) ^ set(b) )

print(a1)
print(b1)
```